# geom_rug under the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get the `geom_rug` below the x-axis (outside the plot) in the following example:

```
set.seed(1)
Time = seq( as.Date('2010-10-01'),as.Date('2010-11-01'),'2 day' )
Var1 = sample (length(Time)) 
Var2 = sample (length(Time)) 

tibble(Time, Var1, Var2) %>%
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -Time) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rug(sides = 'b') +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ .,  scales = 'free')
```

[image]
How would I do that ?

Comment: `geom_rug` is [hard-coded](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-rug.r) to occupy 3% of the plot panel space inside each border. I don't think there's an easy way to move it out. Would using a theme that doesn't show the panel border help? The rug would appear to be very near / almost outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has become a feature in the most recent version of ggplot2 3.2.0
as shown on this page https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_rug.html,
this is done using:

```
# increase the line length and
# expand axis to avoid overplotting
p + geom_rug(length = unit(0.05, "npc")) +
   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0.1))
```